# How to init a structure array in C?

Tags: c, struct, arm, iar

I'm coding on a development board with an ARM processor, so I use IAR WORKBENCH as IDE. I wonder why compiler gives me an error when training to manually initialize an array of structures, code is below:
*Struct definition:*

```
typedef void (*Function)(void);

typedef struct _Task
{
    uint8_t priority;
    Function *func;
    uint8_t exec_state;
}Task;
```

*Attempt to initialize an array of structure:*

```
Task* task_array_test[3] = {
        HIGH , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE,
        MED , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE,
        LOW , &Reset_LED      , IDLE
};
```

IDLE, LOW, MED, HIGH - are macros with unsigned int values.

*Compiler errors:*

```
Error[Pe144]: a value of type "unsigned int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Task *" 
Error[Pe144]: a value of type "void (*)(void)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Task *" 
Error[Pe146]: too many initializer values
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: you can't initialise it that way - need your own initialisation code.

Comment: Your `task_array_test` is an array of 3 pointers. Maybe you want simply `Task task_array_test[3] = { <whatever> };`

Comment: @artm what do you mean ?

Comment: @pmg The asterisk was not necessary, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First what was already mentioned by @pmg - an array of type `Task` would do, probably no need for an array of pointers `Task*`

In addition you don't need `func` to be of type `Function*` as well:

```
typedef void (*Function)(void);

typedef struct _Task
{
    uint8_t priority;
    Function func;
    uint8_t exec_state;
}Task;
```

Your array initialization would then look like this:

```
Task task_array_test[] = {
        HIGH , Switch_LED_RED , IDLE,
        MED ,  Switch_LED_RED , IDLE,
        LOW ,  Reset_LED      , IDLE
};
```

But I prefer to put every element in braces as well for better reading:

```
 Task task_array_test[] = {
            { HIGH , Switch_LED_RED , IDLE },
            { MED ,  Switch_LED_RED , IDLE },
            { LOW ,  Reset_LED      , IDLE }
    };
```

Comment: @TungstenSteel For sure you would need to change how the functions are called then. Leaving it as pointer is okay imo if you also have cases where no `func` is defined and so `NULL` is valid

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with your code.

First:
The type function is already a Pointer to a function no need to declare it a pointer again. This ends in a pointer to a function pointer.

```
typedef struct _Task
{
    uint8_t priority;
    Function func; // Leave out the *
    uint8_t exec_state;
}Task;
```

Second
The correct way to initialize the array would be like that.

```
Task task_array_test[] = {
    {HIGH , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
    {MED , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
    {LOW , &Reset_LED      , IDLE},
};
```

No Task*, only Task. The empty [] allready specifies it as an array.

Here is a little test Program I wrote to prove it works.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*Function)(void);

static int i;

#define HIGH 10
#define MED  5
#define LOW  1
#define IDLE 1

void Switch_LED_RED(void){
   i++;
}

void Reset_LED(void){
   i++;
}

typedef struct _Task
{
    uint8_t priority;
    Function func;
    uint8_t exec_state;
}Task;

Task task_array_test[] = {
    {HIGH , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
    {MED , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
    {LOW , &Reset_LED      , IDLE},
};

int main(){    
    std::cout << "I starts with the value: " << i << std::endl;
    while (i < 3){
      task_array_test[i].func();  
    }
    std::cout << "I has now the value: " << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize using compound literal, like this:

```
Task* task_array_test[3] = {
        &(Task) {HIGH , Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
        &(Task) {MED , Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
        &(Task) {LOW , Reset_LED      , IDLE}
};
```

You can also do:

```
Task s1 = {HIGH , Switch_LED_RED , IDLE};
Task s2 = {MED , Switch_LED_RED , IDLE};
Task s3 = {LOW , Reset_LED      , IDLE};

Task* task_array_test[3] = {&s1, &s2, &s3};
```

In the structure definition you have `func` member declared as

```
Function *func;
```

which makes `func` pointer to pointer to type because `Function` itself is a pointer:

```
typedef void (*Function)(void);
```

Instead it should be:

```
typedef struct _Task
{
    uint8_t priority;
    Function func;       //Note that * removed
    uint8_t exec_state;
} Task;
```

Also, you don't need to use `&` with function name when assigning it to function pointer. A function name gives the address of function.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need pointers you could do this:

```
Task* task_array_test[] = {
    &(Task){HIGH , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
    &(Task){MED , &Switch_LED_RED , IDLE},
    &(Task){LOW , &Reset_LED      , IDLE},
};
```

Answer (score -3):

**You try this code**

```
struct _Task
{
   int a,b,c;
}Task[3]; 
int main()
{
Task[0].a= HIGH;
Task[0].b= Switch_LED_RED;
Task[0].c= IDLE;
Task[1].a= MED ;
Task[1].b= Switch_LED_RED;
Task[1].c= IDLE;
Task[0].a= LOW ;
Task[0].b= Switch_LED_RED;
Task[0].c= IDLE;
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote does not work. Anyway I found answer thanks to @pmg.